# Find the id of the closest input

Tags: jquery, html

How do I find the id of the closest input?

Here's the html

```
<input type="text" id="input1" size="36" name="input1" value="1" />
<input id="show_upload_image_link_button_1" class="button upload_images" type="button" value="Upload Image" />
```

Here's the jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#show_upload_image_link_button_1").click(function() {
    alert(id of input1);
});
});
```

Comment: Closest parent or sibling?

Comment: Something like `$(this).siblings('input').attr('id')`?

Comment: actually you probably want to use `.prev()` based on your provided code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you probably trying to say the closest previous input. So, you can get the `id` of one like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tWb32/)**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show_upload_image_link_button_1").click(function() {
        alert($(this).prev('input').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

If your targeted input is the second input, you could do .next instead like this:

```
$("#input1").click(function() {
        alert($(this).next('input').attr('id'));
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For the closest parent, you can use:

```
$(this).closest('input').attr('id');
```

For the closest (older) sibling, you can use:

```
$(this).prev('input').attr('id');
```

For the closest (younger) sibling, you can use:

```
$(this).next('input').attr('id');
```

If you need to determine closest sibling (older/younger), you will have to write a custom function to determine the index of each in relation to the index of the context element:

```
var closestSibling = null;
var older = $(this).prev('input').attr('id');
var younger = $(this).next('input').attr('id');
var siblings = $(this).siblings('input').add(this);

var currentIndex = $(siblings).index(this);
var olderIndex = $(siblings).index(older);
var youngerIndex = $(siblings).index(younger);

if (Math.abs(youngerIndex-currentIndex) > Math.abs(olderIndex-currentIndex)) {
    closestSibling = older;
}
else {
    closestSibling = younger;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`.siblings('input')`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#show_upload_image_link_button_1").click(function () {
        alert($(this).siblings('input').attr('id'));
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TkHLC/)